# join of two sql tables

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables and I want to join them to get the desired output. 
Say the 1st table (seat1) is

[image]

and the 2nd table (collegestudents) is

[image]

The desired output is

[image]

I have tried the below code. But it fails to give the desired result.

```
    $rde2=mysqli_query($con, "select * from seat1 s
                              left JOIN collegestudents c ON c.Roll = s.Roll
                              ");            




     Any help please.
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: My query renders only roll nos 2 3, 5

Comment: . . Your query should return 5 rows.  The `roll` might get confused, but there should be data for five rows not three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `left join`. Your query looks fine, but you would need not to use `select *`, and instead explictly list the columns that you want to select, using table prefixes. Otherwise, since you have a `Roll` column in both tables, a name clashes will happen, that your application apparently does not handle well.

```
select 
    s.Roll,
    c.Name,
    s.Subject
from seat1 s
left join collegestudents c on c.Roll = s.Roll
```